# Content Management system recommendations

Tags: content-management-system, content-management, ecm

Management is thinking of changing out Content Management Systems. What do you use/recommend?

1. What UCM solution is your company using?
2. How big is your company?
3. Are you happy with the implementation?

Current setup:

1. The company I work for uses `Oracle ECM` (formerly Stellent UCM).
2. We have somewhere over 10,000 employees across Australia, New
   Zealand and Indonesia.
3. It works! Having worked with the system for a while now. I can see
   where the initial implementation went wrong. Its 3 years later and
   it is *Rewrite Time!* (Three year itch?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) CMS: [Oracle's BEA Aqualogic](http://www.bea.com/framework.jsp?CNT=index.htm&FP=/content/products/aqualogic/)
2) Size: 10,000+
3) Experience: As an end user with full community and content admin privileges, I find the tool to be outdated and stifling in terms of knowledge sharing and trying to get the benefits that exist in social networks. Perhaps this is due to the implementation, and not an inherent weakness in the product. Not sure of the future direction of the product either, since Oracle recently acquired it.

Comment: SO really wanted an official Answer.. the winner is Gary!
More of a survey than a question, but what SO wants, SO gets!

Answer (score 1):

Our external business orientated site is running [joomla](http://www.joomla.org/) which once you get passed the learning procces of how it constructs sites, is very good for a multi-user environement.

Company = 25+ people

Answer (score 1):

We use Plone open source for the internal site...

Answer (score 1):

We use a DotNetNuke intranet site. I think we need to upgrade or redesign cause I like Joomla much more.

Answer (score 1):

1) We are moving from Microsoft Content Managemet Server 2002 to Sitecore 6.0 though we have internal PHP Wikis and Dot Net Nuke sites that have user content as well.

2) 1,000-2,000 people with about 3500 pages of Web content to migrate.

3) I'm content with it so far.  There is still a lot of work to do in the migration and it will probably take a couple of years to move everything over, which includes legacy ASP and ASP.Net 1.1 and 2.0 sites that haven't been worked on in a few years as well.  It would take a lot of things going easily for me to be happy with an implementation of this size.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal.  I've used it for small and medium sized projects.

Answer (score 1):

1) We're using a CMS that was custom written in vbscript and sucks horribly.  We're going to start using MODx for our external stuff, but we're not sure what's going to happen with our internal stuff.

2) A university with about 30,000 students (about 10,000 of which have ties to my department).

3) MODx looks cool, but haven't had much of a chance to use it.  As stated previously, our other CMS sucks.

Answer (score 1):

Tridion. And yes, there is that 3-year itch. Is Oracle on a new release or did the first implementation just look wrong now? I remember Stellent being on the development team's shortlist.

Us:
Mid-sized (small?) 700+ employee company, with over a dozen websites, but not all sites have the CMS implemented. In-house development team has worked on, and still support, a few custom solutions. Legacy code never dies. :-)

All of the CMS we researched had compelling features, but for content re-use, cross-site sharing, and programmability we found Tridion to be a good fit (compared to Ektron and RedDot). Our mandate was to stay ".NET programmers" and not have the tool take over the site.

I'm comfortable with and like with Tridion, but admire those of you who've done CMS with multiple platforms.

Comment: Stellent was bought by Oracle a little while back. It took a while but there is a new release out that merges UCM with WebCenter. EDIT: I say 'while' but its more like 2 years now O_o time flies!

Answer (score 0):

1) My [company](http://searchlightdigital.com/) currently uses [Word Press](http://wordpress.com/) or no CMS at all. We are however working on a CMS that will work exactly as we want it to.

2) It's me and my friend so 2 of us

3) We're still starting up and finding clients so haven't had a chance to use it.

Answer (score 0):

In my daily work, I use Tridion, and some of my colleagues use Hippo. At home I use Plone.

Answer (score 0):

Institution-wide we see a variety of systems.

A few Plone sites. I'm a Plone fan.

The centre within which I work is somewhat multi-institutional (a good history of collaborative work) (one of two research centres situated within the same building) and the Plone sites that I'm setting up are fitting very nicely with diverse user/group requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Companies I worked for usually developed CMS systems inhouse I've mostly worked for webshops and when cranking out websites is your core business the best way to get an edge is to be on top of this sort of thing.

So custom CMSes for:

Simplicity, just deliver what the client wants and nothing else.

Understanding it, it's developed in house so you can usually just talk to the guy who wrote it.

Profit, it's easier to ask for license fees.

Answer (score -1):

1. We use the Alterian Content Manager application. It is very robust and suites our needs well.
2. 20000 staff+
3. Very happy. Developers and business team find the application very easy to work with.