# which content magement system to use, if any

Tags: language-agnostic, content-management

I am required to design a website where displaying content is the key functionality.

This is a [similar site](http://www.idea.gov.uk/idk/core/page.do?pageId=8847644), so you can imagine the amont of content. Of course the design depends on preferences.

As i am planing the design I was thinking if such a website would require some kind of content management system (as I would imagine the client may want to modify the content som day), eventhough, it me it seems as a static (html ) site.

considering that it would not be modified daily (therefore is not as dinamic as a blog) I though it would be easier to create the content management side myself without using a content management sysm creater. but again, is there any pre-made content management systems which would me easier to use by me (as developing) and by the client (when/if he needs to modify content)

at the moment, I have used wordpress, so I guess other content management systems (most suited to this project) many not be difficult to use

hope you can advice me on the best content management system to use for the nature of the website

ALSO (slightly of topic) there are lots of posts such as "creating a succesfull online (portfolio)"
is there any post or forum posts wrich lists what a social enterprising website would require.

thanks a lot

aurel

Answer (score -1, accepted):

These may offer some insight:

[what-content-management-system-do-you-use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536791/what-content-management-system-do-you-use)
[what-content-management-does-your-workplace-use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19445/what-content-management-does-your-workplace-use)

As for the second question, I'm not sure the answer to that.

Answer (score -1):

I would build the website as a static site, either using just html/javascript or using a framework like React/Angular or a static site generator. This gives way more freedom, security and speed compared with any CMS you could use.

To allow your clients to do content edits without having to touch the code, you can use a tool [like Instant](https://instant.cm). They offer content management capabilities for static websites.